# nhibernate mapping for entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have `FormTemplate` entity in my project, and I have `Questionnaire` entity which contains FormTemplate

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Argussoft.BI.DAL.Domain.Questionnaires;
using Argussoft.BI.DAL.Domain.FormTemplates;

namespace Argussoft.BI.DAL.Domain.Questionnaires
{
    public class Questionnaire : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual FormTemplate FormTemplate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? DateCreation { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionnaireStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual int Respondent { get; set; }
    }

    public class QuestionnaireMap : BaseEntityMap<Questionnaire>
    {
        public QuestionnaireMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Name).Unique();
            Map(x => x.FormTemplate);
            Map(x => x.DateCreation);
            References(x => x.Status).Column("Status");
            Map(x => x.Respondent);
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do mapping for `FormTemplate` ?

Comment: Is FormTemplate comming from a 3rd party does it have a database representation?

Comment: Can you post the FormTemplate entity class and the mapping for this class (that is if you have created it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should map FormTemplate using References() method.

```
    public QuestionnaireMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Unique();
        References(x => x.FormTemplate).Column("FormTemplate");
        Map(x => x.DateCreation);
        References(x => x.Status).Column("Status");
        Map(x => x.Respondent);
    }
```

Also, if property name on an entity and column name on a table are the same, you can eliminate usage of Column() method.